# Parsear una fecha en formato "Fri Jul 24 1987 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (GMT-06:00)"

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs, express, momentjs

Tengo el siguiente problema.
Al traer una fecha de la base de datos, esta se muestra en otra zona horaria, lo que deseo es la fecha al mostrarse se muestre con la zona horaria del servidor y no la del equipo que accede al portal.
Para esto es utilizado la librería **momentJS** sin embargo al intentar crear el objeto moment este no es creado correctamente:

```js
moment( fecha[i].textContent)
```

Ya que me da este resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Podriamos pensar que el objeto funciona es correcto debido a las validaciones **_isAMomentObject** y **_is Valid**, sin embargo si intento hacer operaciones como **add** o **subtract**, estas no funcionan.

Por ello decidí parsear el objeto pero desconozco como hacerlo. He leido la documentacion de momentJS pero no menciona como parsear este formato, por lo que veo es conocido como **RFC 2822**.
Lo mas que he encontrado en la documentacion de moment es lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero puedan ayudarme les agradezco de antemano compañeros.
Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Saludos**

Espero sea lo que necesitas; cierto que lanza un mensaje de advertencias, pero las operaciones las realiza sin problema.

```js
var laFechaString ='Fri Jul 24 1987 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (GMT-06:00)';
var laFecha = moment(laFechaString);

console.log("*****ANTES DE RESTAR DIAS*****");
console.log("Objeto momentJS:", laFecha);
console.log("Javascript Date:", laFecha.toDate());
console.log("*****LUEGO DE RESTAR DIAS*****");
laFecha.add(-7, 'days');
console.log("Objeto momentJS:", laFecha);
console.log("Javascript Date:", laFecha.toDate());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Gracias a tu post pude notar mi error.
Un gran saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Debería bastar con pasarle el formato al moment

```
var DATE_RFC2822 = "ddd, DD MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss ZZ";
moment(fecha[i].textContent).format(DATE_RFC2822);
```

Comment: Quieres decir que primero lo parsee con el metodo new Date de Js y depues lo convierta a un objeto moment?
Mi intención es usar esta libreria gracias a las facilidades que otorga.
Gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: ahh vale, te entiendo, edito la respuesta con la mask para moment